# What is this game with two boards and pieces numbered 1-15?

Tags: identify-this-game

My in-laws found this in their garage but w have no idea what it is. Seems to be made by MB but it has no other markings on it. Any ideas appreciated.

[image]

Comment: it looks like the backs are designed to attach to *something*. each other, maybe? or perhaps they're just pieces of a larger game? are there any features on the backs that might help?

Comment: Turns out they attach to each other. Possibly some sort of travel game.

Comment: MB is Milton Bradley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Top 15](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/28906/top-15) (also known as Numbers Up!).

[image]